# Casting Object to ? type as parameter of List

Tags: java

Why Java cannot cast `MyObject` to `?` ?
This is the error I get:

```
java.util.List<MyMessage<MyObject>> cannot be converted to java.util.List<MyMessage<?>>
```

when I try to pass:

```
List<MyMessage<MyObject>> x = ...
```

to method:

```
void foo (List<MyMessage<?>> x) {
...
}
```

Comment: Generics are not covariant. You’d need to accept `List<? extends MyMessage<?>>`. The main function this will have is to prevent `add` from working - this will protect the integrity of the inbound `List`. Otherwise you could `add` a `MyMessage<String>` to your `List<MyMessage<MyObject>>` - and nothing good would come of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your `MyMessage` class looked like:

```
class MyMessage<T> {
  T object;
}
```

You are currently able to add things to `x` inside the method:

```
void foo (List<MyMessage<?>> x) {
  MyMessage<String> myMessage = ...;
  x.add(myMessage);
}
```

If you were allowed to pass a `List<MyMessage<MyObject>>`, then you'd be able to do this:

```
List<MyMessage<MyObject>> list = new ArrayList<>();
foo(list);  // Pretend this isn't a compiler error.
MyObject message = list.get(0).object;
```

And now you'd get a `ClassCastException`, because `list.get(0).object` is a `String`, not a `MyObject`.

"But my class doesn't look like that", you might say: the compiler doesn't know there are no fields or provider methods that could return a `T` (or something involving `T`; so it errs on the side of caution, and prevents you from doing it.

In order to avoid the problem, make it so you can't add to the list in `foo`:

```
void foo (List<? extends MyMessage<?>> x) {
  MyMessage<String> myMessage = ...;
  // x.add(myMessage);  // Would be a compiler error!
}
```